# Enabling focus listeners on the composite container

Tags: java, swt, composite

I have four composites aligned in order.

Each composite has a check box, Label, and 2 Buttons. Now these composites are aligned one after another.

I want to enable focus on these items, i.e. when I use <kbd>tab</kbd> to go from one composite to other, the current composite should look highlighted. Ideally I want it to behave like a list, when you choose an item then that gets highlighted. Is this possible?

I understand that composite acts as a container for others widgets, control. My requirement is that I have a list of 5 entries, and that each item in the list has a check box, label, and two Buttons. I would also want it to be focused on when they are selected.

Also please let me know alternative solutions for the same UI that I have described above.

Comment: Could you please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to help us understand your challenge?

Answer (score 1):

To make tab go from composite to composite, set the tab list for each composite to be one control that you want to have focus after a tab. For example, the check box:

```
composite.setTabList(new Control[]{checkButton});
```

To make the highlight, your imagination is the limit. You can change background, add some border, you name it. You just have to update it whenever one of the controls from the composite get focus.

Here is a full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    createElement(shell);
    createElement(shell);
    createElement(shell);
    createElement(shell);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createElement(final Composite parent) {
    final Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
    final Button checkButton = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    final Button button1 = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
    final Button button2 = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
    Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            for (Control control : parent.getChildren()) {
                control.setBackground(null);
            }
            composite.setBackground(composite.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
            if (event.widget == button1 || event.widget == button2) {
                checkButton.setFocus();
            }
        }
    };
    checkButton.addListener(SWT.FocusIn, listener);
    button1.addListener(SWT.FocusIn, listener);
    button2.addListener(SWT.FocusIn, listener);
    composite.setTabList(new Control[]{checkButton});
}
```